# Menus not added to drop down after resizing screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building  responsive menus for that i have taken ordered list and unordered 
list and using css for look and feel for menus.I have wrote script for adding menus dynamically
to the drop down but the problem is that when i resizes screen nothing shown on screen except 
background color of bodyin a script i am trying to build dynamic drop down which
will hold your actual menus

```
         <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mycss.css"  />
            </head>
            <div class="menu-wrap">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Movies <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">T.V. Shows</a></li>
                        <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Site Help</a></li>
                    </ul>





                </nav>

            </div>
          <script>

                        $("<select />").appendTo("nav");

        // Create default option "Go to..."
                        $("<option />", {
                            "selected": "selected",
                            "value": "",
                            "text": "Go to..."
                        }).appendTo("nav select");

        // Populate dropdown with menu items
                        $("nav a").each(function () {
                            var el = $(this);
                            $("<option />", {
                                "value": el.attr("href"),
                                "text": el.text()
                            }).appendTo("nav select");
                        });

                        $("nav select").change(function () {
                            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                        });


                    </script>
        </body>
        </html>
          This is my css file where i am displaying and hiding menus according to the screen sizes
                    nav select
                    {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    @media (max-width: 600px) {
                      nav ul     { display: none; }
                      nav select { display: inline-block; }
                    }

                <!-- end snippet -->

                         nav select
                            {
                                display: none;
                            }

                            @media (max-width: 600px) {
                              nav ul     { display: none; }
                              nav select { display: inline-block; }
                            }
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ConvertMenuToDropdown/

Answer (score 0):

Your tags suggest you are using Bootstrap. But I don't see any Bootstrap-Classes in your HTML.

Did you already look at the [Bootstrap NavBar Example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)? Isn't this exactly what you want?

So how about using [Bootstrap's NavBar Component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), add the Bootstrap-JavaScript, which needs to have the [Collapse-Plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), and have Boostrap do that for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the navbar created using Bootstrap

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Movies <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">T.V. Shows</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Site Help</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```